# Airbnb does not show up in ESLint init style guides

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, vite, eslint-config-airbnb

Trying to setup ESLint with Airbnb style guide for my new React Vite Typescript project.

After running `npx eslint --init` and `npm init @eslint/config`, and selecting all the aforementioned options, I still can't find the Airbnb style guide option in the list. The list only shows Standard and XO.

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is expected since Google and Airbnb do not officially support Typescript. (https://github.com/iamturns/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript#setup)

Instead, it looks like you can use [eslint-config-airbnb-typescript](https://github.com/iamturns/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript#setup)

Answer (score 2):

Airbnb and Google options would show up earlier. However the options have now been removed ([fix: remove airbnb/google in style guides when using ts)](https://github.com/eslint/create-config/pull/33)